# Is it possible to create a "client to client" system for Android?

Tags: android, client

I wonder if it's possible to create a "client to client" system for Android, so that user A can send a serialized object or something similar to user B, without sending it to a server first. The main point of this is to avoid huge server costs, but also the hacking risk.

**EDIT:** I want it to reach about 1000 km, or even more, if possible.

All answers and thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?

Comment: The one who downvoted just disabled my ability to vote up. Thanks.

Comment: wi-fi direct? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Comment: That seems good. Haven't got enough time to read it all, but how far away can each phone be from the other? Is it the same principle as with Bluetooth?

Comment: Okay, now I read it. Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [wi-fi direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

```
Using these APIs, you can discover and connect to other devices when 
each device supports Wi-Fi P2P, then communicate over a speedy 
connection across distances much longer than a Bluetooth connection.
```

Comment: I just have one little question. Roughly how far will it reach? 1 km? 10 km? 100 km? More?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586003/range-of-distances-in-which-wi-fi-direct-works it says up to 100 meters

Comment: Hmm... That's a bit too short for my purposes, but I'll let the answer be accepted anyways, because it solves the question in general. Is there any other options? Can you send data through Google+ with the Google+ api?

Comment: no there isn't only wifi direct and bluetooth 4.0 (both have a range of ~100 meters). if you need distances > 1000 km then you have to use a backend server. look into parse.com they offer backend services for free up to a limit of requests. there may be other similar services.

Answer (score 0):

The currently best solution, for short range, < 100 meters, seems to be Wifi direct (WiFi peer to peer), as Goran Horia Mihail mentioned.

If you need something for a longer distance, like me, you should take a look at Parse, www.parse.com, as 
Goran Horia Mihail also mentioned.